# nodeName for selected text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a HTML text editor.
For this,i have a div with contenteditable set to true.
For making a selected text "bold",i am trying to find node of the selected text.
How should i do this or is there is any other way to implement this(particular in ie).

Comment: what do you mean by "node of the selected text"?

Comment: [This](http://blog.siteroller.net/understanding-javascript-selection-and-range) and [this](http://blog.siteroller.net/understanding-the-js-range-object-part-2-home) are great articles that explain how to get the selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please be aware that a user's selection is not directly related to a node in the DOM.  Consider this HTML fragment:

```
<p>
    Now <b>is the time</b> for all <u>good men</u>
    to come <i>to the <em>aid</em> of their</i>
    country.
</p>
```

Suppose the user's selection extends from the beginning of "time" to the end of "country".  There are at least 12 nodes involved:

1. Part of a text node: "time"
2. The end tag of a `<b>` node.
3. A text node: " for all "
4. A complete `<u>` node, with a child node:

   - A text node "good men"
5. A text node: " to come "
6. A complete `<i>` node, with child nodes:

   - A text node: "to the "
   - A complete `<em>` node, with a child node:
   - - A text node: "aid"
   - A text node: " of their"
7. Part of a text node: " country" (note, the complete text node includes a period, but the selection does not.)

So, you can't really ask for the nodeName, because there are a lot of nodes here.

You can, however, ask "What is the nodeName of a container that completely encloses the user's selection, even if it might also enclose things that are not selected?"

If that is what you want to know, you need the [TextRange.parentElement()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536654.aspx) method (for IE only, other browsers would use the [range.commonAncestorContainer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.commonAncestorContainer) property).

For example, in IE:

```
window.document.selection.createRange().parentElement().nodeName;
```

That gets you the nodeName, as you state in your question title.  This is different from wanting to make the text bold, which you indicate in your question text.  If you want to make the text bold, you probably want the [TextRange.execCommand()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536419.aspx) method.

```
window.document.selection.createRange().execCommand('Bold', false);
```

And that should make the selection bold.  A [list of possible commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533049.aspx) exists.

Comment: Using the `execCommand()` method of the `TextRange` is obviously IE-only and unnecessary if you're working with the selection. `document.execCommand()` will work just as well and works in all major browsers. Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Internet_Explorer_Differences

Answer (score 0):

This will return the nodeName for you however you decide to get the selected text:

```
$("your-selector-here").context.nodeName;
```